what is "viewport" mentioned in the raytracing in one weekend book?
I'm trying to make a simple raytracer following the raytracing in one weekend book, but I couldn't understand why is he using what is called a viewport, he define it as a virtual rectangle, why don't we just shoot the rays directly in the window, a window with 500x500 would have the camera on [x=250,y=250,z=0] and we shoot them from pixel [0,0,-1] to pixel [499,499,-1], why is he taking the effort to create another rectangle with 2.0 in the height.... can anyone help me with a very simple and forward answer?

I am not sure if there is anything special happening because it is raytracing (I have limited knowledge of raytracing), however generally a viewport is just the output location for a camera.
Imagine you have a scene with 4 cameras in it, you may choose to divide your real screen (monitor) into 4 quadrants and then render each camera to a separate quadrant. Each of those quadrants would be a viewport.
Note: In the same way that in the real world you can have a camera connected to a TV, you can do the same thing in the game world and have the output of a camera rendered to a surface inside the game world, this case is a little fuzzy - some would call it a (Sub)ViewPort some might call it a Render Target.
TL;DR - what a camera "sees" is somewhat logical - which may not be directly connected to a particular monitor, that logical indirection is a viewport.
